# Redis management on Heroku

Tags: python, memory, heroku, redis

I have provisioned Redis To Go addon in Heroku for use with [Redis Queue python library](http://python-rq.org/).  My app is having some issue with the redis DB for the queue (namely max-memory problem).  The memory use stays really high even when all the work has been finished.  So I have been reading up on Redis and Redis Queue, and read all through [Heroku's Redis documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis).

I want to use the command line interface, so I tried installing:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-redis
```

> ▸    Not installing heroku-redis because it is already installed as a
>   core plugin.

OK so the redis to go installed a redis server with the config var `REDISTOGO_URL`, which I can confirm with `heroku config | grep REDIS`.  So then I tried to "promote" this instance:

```
heroku redis:promote REDISTOGO_URL
```

> ▸    No Redis instances found.

and I get no results at all from `heroku redis:info -a appname`

The important thing I am trying to do is change my `maxmemory-policy`, which you are able to do using `heroku redis`, but still I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just for anyone using [Redis To Go](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/redistogo), I switched my Redis server to the free version of [Heroku Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) and all the problems went away.

Redis To Go was telling me in the console that it was using the `volatile-lru` eviction policy but it was still throwing errors for max memory and it wasn't clearing out max memory at all ( 8 MB memory use while doing nothing for hours ).

Using Heroku Redis there were no memory errors while doing even more work on the free tier. At Rest the Redis memory usage went down to below 1MB which is what I would expect.  Also no with Heroku Redis I am able to access the CLI using the `heroku redis` app.

Answer (score 0):

To give your Redis more RAM (i.e. increase max-memory) you just need to upgrade your plan - use `heroku addons:upgrade ...` to do that.

Comment: Yeah I know that.  I am still trying to learn more about Redis.  I just don't understand why it needs so much Ram...  All the queues are empty and it is still holding 8MB of memory.